# Delete fails due to DB exception in updateForeignKeyFieldBeforeDelete

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using Eclipselink and facing issues in delete.
I have `ManyToOne` join as below.

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_CD", nullable=false)
private StudentEntity student;
}
```

While trying to delete `UserEntity`, I am getting the below exception.

```
[#|2013-08-07T20:44:52.105+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction|_ThreadID=35;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cannot update ("SERVICE"."USERS"."STUDENT_CD") to NULL

Error Code: 1407
Call: UPDATE SERVICE.USERS SET STUDENT_CD = ? WHERE (USER_ID = ?)
    bind => [null, 1]

    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.updateObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.updateObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.CallQueryMechanism.updateForeignKeyFieldBeforeDelete(CallQueryMechanism.java:436)
```

It is mentioned as a bug here.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=341709

The issue occurs in Eclipselink 2.4.

Any suggestions?

## UPDATE

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema="SERVICE")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
...
// bi-directional many-to-one association to StudentEntity
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_CD", nullable=false)
private StudentEntity student;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT", schema="SERVICE")
public class StudentEntity implements Serializable {
...
@Id
@Column(name = "STUDENT_CD")
private String studentCd;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
private Set<UserEntity> users;
...
}
```

I am new to JPA. As per my understanding there is no cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include your full class mappings including all relationships, and the full SQL trace.

EclipseLink will only null foreign key during deletion when it detects a cycle.  i.e. you are deleting two or more objects that both reference each other through foreign keys.  Technically there is no way to delete this model, as a deletion from either side will cause a foreign key constraint violation.

You may want to rethink your model to not have a two-way foreign key dependency.  Normally when you have a bidirectional relationship you will use a "mappedBy" on one side so only 1 foreign key is used for both relationships.

If you have a cycle, and not-null constraints, then you may have made your data impossible to be deleted, which is probably a bad idea.  You will need to relax one of the constraints.  If one of the foreign keys is not null and one is nullable, then you can set the nullable one to null yourself before deleting the objects to avoid the cycle.  You can also influence which side EclipseLink nulls using a constraintDependency.

You can also try the 2.5.2 release, which does take into account not null constraints.

Comment: Due to space limitation to comment, I have answered the questions.